# Analytics data deleted from the Azure applicationinsights

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I checked that when i try to query on events data the total record decreased automatically. I want to know that when data is deleted from applicationinsights. My query is just simple count query. I also noticed that some events timestamp also updated. I searched for blog etc but nothing found

```
customEvents | count
```

Comment: There is a [retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-data-retention-privacy#how-long-is-the-data-kept) on the data of 90 days, did you take that in account? Also, what period did you select in analytics?

Comment: application insights is basically a "write once" database.  once records are inserted, they are never updated.  As @PeterBons said, after 90 days, data expires and is no longer available.

Comment: I tried to fetch last 6 month data and due to 90 days limit its is showing less count now. I tried to pull all the data and insert in to the database so i can perform query on that. is there any better way to do it ? as i already using continuous export to copy it to a storage account can i query on the storage account ?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you *explicitly* set a time range in the query directly, like

```
customEvents | where timestamp >= ago(7d) | count
```

then the analytics website is going to automatically apply a last 24 hours time restriction automatically.  (look in the upper right corner, there is a dropdown that will either say "set in query" or "last 24 hours" or other choices)

Comment: I also tried with custom time but this is not the issue some records are actually missing from the log

Comment: I think its due to 90 days limit the data is not coming.